# Java's way of implementing interface methods in derived class

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

While developing some demo application, I came accross a situation like below.

I have basically 3 classes among others:

```
-One interface MyInterface

-One base class MyBaseClass

-One derived class MyDerivedClassExtendsMyBaseClass
```

In this structure, MyBaseClass implements MyInterface. Java forces me to implement the methods of MyInterface in the MyBaseClass.

When MyDerivedClassExtendsMyBaseClass also implements MyInterface, Java does not force me to implement the methods of MyInterface. It is up to me to override MyInterface methods.

```
public interface MyInterface{

   public void myMethod();

}

public class MyBase implements MyInterface{

   //some members and methods here

   @Override
   public void myMethod(){
      //You have to implement myMethod
   }
}

public class MyDerivedClassExtendsMyBaseClass extends MyBase implements MyInterface{

    //You don't have to implement myMethod() here!!
}
```

Is there a special purpose for this? Why I don't have to implement the method of interface MyInterface although my derived class implements it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your Derived Class extending `MyBase` Class  and it has already forced to implement methods of `MyInterface`. Since Derived class is a child of `MyBase` , it can inherit from super class, hence there is no need of implement them again. There is always an implementation for it (right now from parent).

If you remove the extends, again you will be forced to implement in derived class.

Comment: But when you check Oracle's page explaining interface, it says:

"If your class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class will successfully compile."
In my situation, there is a class claims to implement the interface MyInterface but the code of myMethod does not necessarily in the source code of my derived class.
Through inheritance, definition of myMethod is inherited in my derived class but does it really mean, my derived class have the definition of myMethod in its source code?

Comment: @UgurKAYA Exactly. All the parent source code packed into child source code.